# How to copy contents of list to excel

Tags: excel, python-3.x

Setup: I am using jupyter notebook, Python version 3.6.2, and Excel version 15.36

Task: I have created a list and want to copy its contents in order to the first row of a blank Excel file, column by column.

Here is my code:

```
for rowOfCellObjects in strauss_sheet(1, list_length):
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
        for item in noreplist:
            sheet.cellObj(row=1, column=colNum).value = item
```

I am getting an error since 'Worksheet' object is not callable. 
I have the length of my list stored in list_length, and my list is `noreplist`.

I am new to python and would love to hear a good way to execute this task.

Comment: are you using [openpyxl](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl), do you prefer to use a particular python package to do this?

Comment: @downshift Yes, I am using openpyxl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done quite easily with [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt):

```
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

listdata = ['write', 'list', 'to', 'excel', 'row']

first_row = 0

# write each item in the list to consecutive columns on the first row
for index, item in enumerate(listdata):
        ws.write(first_row, index, item) 

wb.save('example.xls')
```

produces excel file with contents:

[image: write list to excel row]

Hope this helps.